# How do you append a React Component to an html element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, dom-manipulation

I tried to add a React.icon too my button, but it's a react component (with this syntax: ). My question now is how can I append this exact icon component to my button Element with DOM Manipulation?
This is my current code:

```
        const para = document.createElement("p");
        const node = document.createTextNode("New Button");
        const uList = document.getElementById("uList");
        const btn = <button ><BsIcons.BsClockHistory /></button>
        listEl.appendChild(btn);
        para.appendChild(node);
        listEl.appendChild(para);
        uList.appendChild(listEl);
```

Comment: You don't. Why would you do this? React do `createElement` for you. You shouldn't ever use it by yourself.

Comment: Did you develop/create the React.Icon component ? In that case you can append in the `componentDidMount` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append React components to HTML element using .append()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59899729/how-to-append-react-components-to-html-element-using-append)

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Could you elaborate further? I'm kinda new to React and the docs can't help me further sadly

Comment: Please first read how to use it https://beta.reactjs.org/learn

Answer (score 0):

You can build a Web Component from the React Code and then append it to any HTML element.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).